# Video plays in Firefox, but not on Chrome/Opera

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-video

At the website that I host https://shinesolar.com I have a video for the banner on the homepage. Well all of a sudden (no code changes were made to the website) today, the video stopped working. What happens is a flash of the video appears for a second, then a black background just takes its place. The video is still there because I can right click it and open it in a new tab, and it plays. Also, when I refresh the page *sometimes* the video plays. But rarely, if ever does it happen when you just navigate to the page. It also does not work in Incognito mdoe
HOWEVER, it works fine in Firefox. So I don't know what's going on here. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google changed it's video `autoplay` policy

You have to make the video `muted`

```
<video id="video" muted autoplay>
```

You can check it [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes)

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem.
I changed the property 'muted' to true using jQuery

```
$('video').prop("muted",true);
```

Comment: This only works when you have the attribute already, in case you dont have  then $('video').attr("muted",true); will help